# How to make the package manager npm use bash 4 on Mac OS X?

Tags: node.js, macos, bash, shell, npm

I've [updated bash to version 4 on Mac OS X Yosemite using homebrew](http://clubmate.fi/upgrade-to-bash-4-in-mac-os-x/), in order to make it possible to use "globstar" in my npm scripts. E.g. recursively list all .js files in `test` directory using the pattern `./test/**/*.js`. However, npm will run scripts with older bash version (version 3).

Is it possible to make npm uses the updated bash version?

(I'm not sure, but I guess npm uses /bin/bash instead of /usr/local/bin/bash)

UPDATE: My particular use case is to investigate the possibilities to use npm as a build tool, and for instance bundle all test specs with browserify using a npm script such as `"build:test:scripts": "browserify ./test/**/*.js -o /build/test-bundle.js",`.

Comment: Why not just accomplish that via `find`? Seems like relying on a specific bash version will be very non-portable

Comment: I've updated the question with my particular use case. Not sure if or how `find` could be applicable(?)

Comment: `find ./test -type f -name "*.js" | xargs browserify -o ./build/test-bundle.js` for example I'd expect to work fine.

Comment: Thanks loganfsmyth. The workaround is good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the "globstar" with single quotes:

```
"build:test:scripts": "browserify './test/**/*.js' -o /build/test-bundle.js",
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the `script-shell` config key to the path of your Bash 4 installation.

> **[script-shell](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#script-shell):** The shell to use for scripts run with the `npm run` command.

```
# local
npm config set script-shell "/usr/local/bin/bash"

# global
npm config set -g script-shell "/usr/local/bin/bash"
```

Comment: Thank you! and `npm config set script-shell $SHELL` will set the shell to the shell you're currently using.